# How include "sthread.h" in C

Tags: c, header

I am reading some book(Operating Systems Principles and Practice 2012) and I have example with C code with threads.`
And I can't use header pthread.h. Where I can take code for this header or where I can find something about it?Also do I need special additionals when I compile it on Windows.Thanks every one:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static void go(int n);

#define NTHREADS 10
static pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ii;

    for(ii = 0; ii < NTHREADS; ii++)
    {
        pthread_create(&(threads[ii]), &go, ii);
    }

    for(ii = 0; ii < NTHREADS; ii++)
    {
        long ret = pthread_join(threads[ii]);
        printf("Thread %d returned %ld\n", ii, ret);
    }

    printf("Main thread done.\n");
    return 0;
}

void go(int n)
{
    printf("Hello from thread %d\n", n);
    pthread_exit(100 + n);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `pthread.h`?

Comment: Check whether the book gives some background info about that threading library. Further, check how old that book is. It could be that it uses some ancient or obsolete libraries. BTW: Which book? That would be a valuable info to add to your question.

Comment: yeah please mention the source, never heard of `sthread.h`

Comment: Maybe pthread.h , I don't know because I saw this code in the book.And I can't figure out with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I can't use header pthread.h. Where I can take code for this header or where I can find something about it?

It's part of your operating system. If you don't have it, you can't.

> Also do I need special additionals when I compile it on Windows.

Yes, you need to know that Windows doesn't have pthreads.

Comment: @LittleMax Did you try Googling something like: c threads windows?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find answer.Can you send me link with answer, please?:)

Comment: There are implementations of the POSIX thread API for use under MS Windows.